# Query an Ip address in KQL

Tags: azure, kql, azure-sentinel

Am quite new to this, I am trying to get a query to search logs for Ip address activity in Microsoft sentinel using KQL, any help would be much appreciated.

I just don't know the right query to use for this .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the search operator.

See chapter 4 of the Must Learn KQL series for an easy walkthrough: https://aka.ms/MustLearnKQL

Comment: Thanks so much, The link really helped my understanding, and the search operator was very useful.